# PhpSpreadSheet how to have a new line?

Tags: phpspreadsheet

Good day everyone i want to achieve a new line in my spreadsheet cause i had two to three values here

This code over here has a protection so the viewers cannot edit easily in excell they must have password on the admin to be enable to edit.

```
  $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSort(true);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setInsertRows(true);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setFormatCells(true);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setPassword('test');
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
        $spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()
                    ->getFont()
                    ->setName('Times New Roman')
                    ->setSize(14);

        $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Control Number');
        $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Requesting Unit');
        $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Project Details');
        $sheet->setCellValue('D1', 'Attached Transaction Form');
```

This line of code uses to fetch the data in the database in this scenario my attached form has two to three values so thats why i want to create a break or a new line.

```
 $data = $this->m->getlog1();
        $slno = 1;
        $start = 2;
        foreach($data as $d){
            $sheet->setCellValue('A'.$start, $d->control_number);
            $sheet->setCellValue('B'.$start, $d->requesting_unit);
            $sheet->setCellValue('C'.$start, $d->project_details);
            $sheet->setCellValue('D'.$start, $d->attached_form);
        
            
        $start = $start+1;
        $slno = $slno+1;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use line breakes in the text and

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

For more Information see [documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#write-a-newline-character-n-in-a-cell-altenter).

According to this commit this [commit](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/commit/22190615ce4a0555d70c32c56e7f7b8a3288bb2c) this will be automatically included in future releases.

Maybe you must/will use some auto fit then take a look to this [code](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/333).